# Question about setup Astar zkEVM Permissionless RPC Node

Tags: zkevm, astar

I'm tksarah, I'm trying to setup Astar zkEVM Permissionless RPC Node by reading the Astar docs(https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/zkEVM/zk-node/setup-rpc-node).

After starting docker container and then testing RPC request.
There was an error below

```
tk@zkevm:~$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "eth_chainId", "params": []}' http://localhost:8545
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

According to logs of zkevm-sync, it seems to start the syncing.

```
sudo docker logs -fn30 zkevm-sync
{"level":"info","ts":1700707719.584979,"caller":"nileventstorage/nileventstorage.go:34","msg":"Event: &{Id:{neg:false abs:[]} ReceivedAt:2023-11-23 02:48:39.584876989 +0000 UTC m=+10.821702602 IPAddress: Source:node Component:synchronizer Level:info EventID:NODE COMPONENT STARTED Description:Running synchronizer Data:[] Json:<nil>}","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707719.585081,"caller":"cmd/run.go:266","msg":"running migrations for zkevm-pool-db","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707719.5851078,"caller":"db/db.go:47","msg":"running migrations up","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707719.613317,"caller":"db/db.go:83","msg":"successfully ran 0 migrations","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"warn","ts":1700707719.632281,"caller":"metrics/prometheus.go:559","msg":"Histogram metric already exists.","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1","metricName":"synchronizer_full_L1_sync_time"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707719.6328094,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:104","msg":"Sync started","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707719.6328754,"caller":"cmd/run.go:549","msg":"metrics server listening on port 9091","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707720.1088386,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:248","msg":"latestSequencedBatchNumber: 152771, latestSyncedBatch: 6255, lastVerifiedBatchNumber: 152747","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707721.2644076,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:314","msg":"Syncing block 4545934 of 4747691","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707721.264507,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:315","msg":"Getting rollup info from block 4545934 to block 4546034","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707728.6945355,"caller":"state/batch.go:354","msg":"Batch: 6256 took 533.335975ms to be processed by the executor ","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700707728.70056,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:1604","msg":"pending flushID: 1","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}

...
(Omitted in the middle)
...

{"level":"info","ts":1700705993.721087,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:1604","msg":"pending flushID: 1582","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700705994.339744,"caller":"state/batch.go:354","msg":"Batch: 6304 took 617.828891ms to be processed by the executor ","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700705994.3410878,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:1604","msg":"pending flushID: 1583","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700705994.358355,"caller":"state/batch.go:354","msg":"Batch: 6305 took 16.422999ms to be processed by the executor ","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
{"level":"info","ts":1700705994.360194,"caller":"synchronizer/synchronizer.go:1604","msg":"pending flushID: 1584","pid":1,"version":"v0.3.1"}
```

Port mapping status:

```
tk@zkevm:~$ sudo docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}"
NAMES            PORTS
zkevm-rpc        0.0.0.0:8545->8545/tcp, :::8545->8545/tcp, 8123/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9091->9091/tcp, :::9091->9091/tcp
zkevm-prover     0.0.0.0:50061->50061/tcp, :::50061->50061/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50071->50071/tcp, :::50071->50071/tcp
zkevm-sync       8123/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9092->9091/tcp, :::9092->9091/tcp
zkevm-pool-db    0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp, :::5433->5432/tcp
zkevm-state-db   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp
tk@zkevm:~$ ss -lt
State                         Recv-Q                        Send-Q                                                 Local Address:Port                                                       Peer Address:Port                        Process
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:9092                                                            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:50061                                                           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                   127.0.0.53%lo:domain                                                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             128                                                          0.0.0.0:ssh                                                             0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:50071                                                           0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:postgresql                                                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:5433                                                            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:8545                                                            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                         0.0.0.0:9091                                                            0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:9092                                                               [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:50061                                                              [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             128                                                             [::]:ssh                                                                [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:50071                                                              [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:postgresql                                                         [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:5433                                                               [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:8545                                                               [::]:*
LISTEN                        0                             4096                                                            [::]:9091                                                               [::]:*
```

What could be the cause? Please let me know if there is anything I should check.

By the way,
I use the Alckemy(Network is Ethereum sepolia) as Ethereum RPC Node.

My environment;

- Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
- CPU Intel N100 x 4 Core / 16GB RAM / M.2 SSD 500GB / 1Gbps Ethernet
- docker image version (zkevm-node: v0.3.1 , zkevm-prover: v2.2.2)

I'm IT infrastructure, virtulization, cloud engineer.
So I have some oss skills such as linux/unix,docker,k8s,openstack,ansible,hadoop and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself.
This was due to a typo in docker-compose.yml to start the container with the original source file.
I have already communicated this to the team. Therefore, this matter will be closed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug, the file has been fixed :)